# JSON file updates but have to refresh multiple times to return back new data in get request

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a site where every time a user enters a city name the JSON file with the city info gets updated. My post to the file works fine but sometimes when I make a get request to it and console.log what cities are in there the new city doesn't appear right away. I have to refresh 1 or multiple times to see it. Other times it shows up right away. Is this a problem with Chrome or with my code? Would really appreciate some help.

Here's my get:

```
$scope.retrieve = function(){
  $http.get("cities.json").success
  (function(data){
    $scope.pic = data;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    console.log(data[i].capital);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("Error "+status);
  });
}
```

Here's my post:

```
$http.post('cityData.php',userdata).success(function(data){
  $scope.retrieve();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   console.log(data[i].city);
  alert("Success!");
});
```

Comment: It sounds like it's being cached and then read from cache instead of actually retrieving the file. On the Chrome Developer Tools' Network tab can you see anything that might give you a hint what the `$http.get` is actually doing?

Comment: Not really. I tried disabling cache but I still have to refresh to make the changes appear.